# How do i add a WAIT in a Web Performance Test loop?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

Writing a Web Performance Test for a process that will run for an undetermined time, and have to put a refresh command in a while that runs until the process state indicates it is done.
The refresh command consumes about 3 seconds. so do not want it running constantly in the loop. So, am trying to find a sleep/wait function to stop the execution between loops.
The only reference i've found is for *Thread.Sleep* which seems to do the job.
**BUT**, this method seems to also stop the test's timers. so, however many times the loop runs, and whatever the actual time taken by the process, the test report will only show the cumulative time of the refresh statements.

Is there another method that will not stop the test's timers?

Answer (score 1):

If the refresh is in a loop within the Web Performance Test then set a suitable "think time" on the request. This will pause the test **after** the response is received. (Think times are normally used to simulate the time a person spends reading a web page and filling in forms etc before the next request is issued.)

Think times are set via the properties of the request. Think times (also reporting names) for all requests in a test can be viewed and modified using the "Set request detail" command accessed using the (rightmost) command icon in eth web test editor.

Think times can also be set or adjusted in the `PreRequest` method of a `WebTestRequest` plugin.

Comment: that does force the loop to pause for whatever time is specified.  
but, this still has the same problem, of the "think time" not being included in the overall time of the transaction or the test. and my test results are useless.

Comment: @muntT Think times **are** included in test times and transaction times, they are excluded from pages and request times. ("Transaction" has a precise meaning in a Visual Studio Web Performance Test.) If think times are important to your results them please edit your question to fully explain what you want.

Comment: nop. sorry. you were right. been reading the transaction times incorrectly. looking at response instead of elapsed times.  
your solution is what i needed. thanks